# Angular2 beta.12 inputs and outputs (formerly properties and events)

Tags: angular

Can someone point me somewhere (or explain here) where i can learn more about outputs in beta 12.  I would like to know how to properly use inputs and outputs.  I am confident with inputs but would like to know more about how to implement outputs.

Comment: Angular2 cookbook - [component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component receives data from its parent via inputs. It can send data back to its parent via outputs.

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  template: '<my-child [label]="buttonLabel" (clicked)="handleClick()"></my-child>',
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
class ParentComponent {
  buttonLabel = 'Very Important Button';
  handleClick() {
    console.log('The button in the child component was clicked!');
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: '<button (click)="clicked.emit($event)">{{label}}</button>'
})
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter;
}
```

Comment: Is doing is that way equivalent to putting `inputs[]` into the `@Component()` For example `@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<p>Hello</p>",
    inputs: ["myproperty"]
})
`
since on my other component i have `<my-app [myproperty] = something></my-app>`

Is there an equivalent of this for the output so that i can put `outputs=[...]` in the decorator and not the class

Comment: Yes, it looks like `@Component`'s object can have an `outputs` property. (See Angular 2's [documentation for ComponentMetadata](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html))